# Add button to Default Dashboard Command Bar - CRM online

Tags: dashboard, dynamics-crm-online

Trying to add Run Report button to Dashboard command bar, tried using Ribbon Workbench , got completely lost is there another way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recheck following article - http://www.develop1.net/public/post/Adding-Auto-Refresh-to-Dashboards.aspx I believe described scenario 50% the same as yours.